# How to remove a field from the parent Form in a subclass?

Tags: python, django, forms, inheritance, field

```
class LoginForm(forms.Form):
    nickname = forms.CharField(max_length=100)
    username = forms.CharField(max_length=100)
    password = forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput)


class LoginFormWithoutNickname(LoginForm):
    # i don't want the field nickname here
    nickname = None #??
```

**Is there a way to achieve this?**

Note: i don't have a `ModelForm`, so the `Meta` class with `exclude` doesn't work.

Answer (score 79, accepted):

You can alter the fields in a subclass by overriding the **init** method:

```
class LoginFormWithoutNickname(LoginForm):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(LoginFormWithoutNickname, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields.pop('nickname')
```

Comment: thank you, please edit the `__init__(self)` to `__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)`

Comment: Didn't work with an inlined admin form, templates try to render them anyway, and I get a KeyError.

Answer (score 13):

Django 1.7 addressed this in commit [b16dd1fe019](https://github.com/django/django/commit/b16dd1fe019b38d0dcdf4a400e9377fb06b33178) for ticket [#8620](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/8620).  In Django 1.7, it becomes possible to do `nickname = None` in the subclass as the OP suggests.  From the documentation changes in the commit:

> It's possible to opt-out from a `Field` inherited from a parent class by shadowing it. While any non-`Field` value works for this purpose, it's recommended to use `None` to make it explicit that a field is being nullified.

Comment: Works?  As "nullified" means that will take value None? Because I tried and using "meta -> exclude =[] " works as I expect, "your" way it use a default value for the field, equal to None

Comment: Note that this will only work when the field is declared by the parent class. In general, this won't work with `ModelForm`s.

Comment: Did tried this solution to remove 'assigned_to' in TicketForm. The field did disappeared from the form as expected but it now throw an error at Ticket creation. The default value is given but it's not in cleaned_data. Is their a way to hide this specific field from the form while it will still be sent via cleaned_data?

Answer (score 5):

I found that, please comment if interested.

(in Django 1.7.4)
extending forms, with following code:

```
class MyForm(forms.ModelForm):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(MyForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        for key, field in self.fields.iteritems():
            self.fields[key].required = False

    class Meta:
        model = MyModel
        exclude = []

    field_1 = forms.CharField(label="field_1_label")
    field_2 = forms.CharField(label="field_2_label", widget=forms.Textarea(attrs={'class': 'width100 h4em'}),)
    field_3 = forms.CharField(label="field_3_label", widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'width100'}),)
    field_4 = forms.ModelChoiceField(label='field_4_label', queryset=AnotherModel.objects.all().order_by("order") )

class MyForm_Extended_1(MyForm):
    field_1 = None


class MyForm_Extended_2(MyForm):
    class Meta:
        model = MyModel
        exclude =[
                    'field_1',
                ]
```

MyForm_Extended_1 set field_1 as None, (the column in db is updated as Null)

MyForm_Extended_2 ignore the field (ignore the column in db during the save)

So, for my purpose, I use the second method.

Comment: Very useful and only way to remove field from forms.Form (without model)

Answer (score 3):

I didn't like the fact (or so I understood) that the exclusion of a field in the second class using "class Meta:" still results in the unused field being in the db.

Perhaps the simplest way is to define an abstract class that has the fields shared by both classes.  Then the two original classes above become subclasses of this new class.  So the example given at the start of this thread might look the following.  It's a bit more code, but this way you extend a subclass rather than do an (incomplete) exclusion from a super class.

```
class LoginForm_Common(forms.Form):
    username = forms.CharField(max_length=100)
    password = forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput)
    class Meta:
        abstract = True

class LoginForm(LoginForm_Common):
    nickname = forms.CharField(max_length=100)

class LoginFormWithoutNickname(LoginForm_Common):
    pass
```