# Exclude django-simple-history from a child model

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-simple-history

I am actually stuck in a problem where I need to exclude HistoricalRecords (django-simple-history) from a child class without making any changes in the parent class.

Here is my code looks like

```
from simple_history.models import HistoricalRecords
class BaseModel(models.Model):
    id = models.UUIDField(...some args...)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(...some args...)
    created_by = models.ForeignKey(...some args...)
    history = HistoricalRecords(inherit=True)

    class Meta:
        abstract = True
        default_permissions = Constants.STANDARD_ACTIONS

    def save(self, suppress_modified=False, from_publish=False, **kwargs):
        super(BaseModel, self).save(**kwargs)


class CommonWithExtraFieldsWithoutVersioning(BaseModel, CommonWithoutVersioning, models.Model):
    class Meta(CommonWithoutVersioning.Meta):
        abstract = True


class Manager(CommonWithExtraFieldsWithoutVersioning):
    from_branch = models.CharField(...some args...)
    to_branch = models.CharField(...some args...)
    from_version = models.IntegerField(...some args...)
    to_version = models.IntegerField(...some args...)
    history = None # this is also not working for me

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):  # this I have tried but not working
        super(DSLJourneyMergeHistory, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.clean_fields('history')
```

But when I try to `makemigration` it is creating HistoricalRecords for the manager as well and I want `HistoricalRecords` should not be maintained for the `class manager`. How do I exclude this as BaseModel and CommonWithExtraFields Models are used across the application and I cannot make any modification in that model

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to remove a field from the parent Form in a subclass?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15557257/how-to-remove-a-field-from-the-parent-form-in-a-subclass)

Comment: @Alvi15 I have tried this as well but didn't work